# How to conditionally chain iterators?

Tags: rust, iterator

Let's say I have:

```
let it = [1, 2, 3].into_iter();
let jt = [4, 5, 6].into_iter();
let kt = [7, 8, 9].into_iter();
```

Then I have boolean conditions `i`, `j` and `k`. I want to generate an iterator that conditionally chains `it`, `jt` and `kt` together based on the values of `i`, `j` and `k`. Can I do this with just the built-in Rust `Iterator` functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make `Option` into an iterator.

```
let it = i.then_some([1, 2, 3]).into_iter().flatten();
let jt = j.then_some([4, 5, 6]).into_iter().flatten();
let kt = k.then_some([7, 8, 9]).into_iter().flatten();
let iter = it.chain(jt).chain(kt);
```

If the condition is false, then `condition.then_some(...)` will return `None`, making an empty iterator. Otherwise a `Some(...)` is returned. `into_iter().flatten()` will transform `Option<impl IntoIterator<Item=T>>` to `impl Iterator<Item=T>`.

Answer (score 6):

You're going to run into a slight issue if you want to use bare iterators:

If you write the following:

```rust
let iter = [1, 2, 3].into_iter();
let iter = if some_condition {
  iter.chain([4, 5, 6])
} else {
  iter
}
```

You'll get an error which boils down to this:

```
  = note: expected struct `std::iter::Chain<std::array::IntoIter<_, _>, std::array::IntoIter<{integer}, 3>>`
             found struct `std::array::IntoIter<_, _>`
```

`iter` has type `IntoIter`, but `iter.chain()` has type `Chain<IntoIter, ...>`

To get around this, you have a few options:

- you can use a trait object, which behaves a bit like an `interface` from languages like Java, but loses some performance:

```rust
let iter = [1, 2, 3].into_iter();
let mut iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>> = Box::new(iter);
if some_condition {
  iter = Box::new(iter.chain([4, 5, 6]));
}
```

- or, probably a better solution, if you can sacrifice laziness, is to just use a `Vec`:

```rust
// save heap allocations by pre-allocating the whole vec
let len = if some_condition { 6 } else { 3 };  
let mut items = Vec::with_capacity(len);

items.extend([1, 2, 3]);
if some_condition {
  items.extend([4, 5, 6]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use for the [`either`](https://crates.io/crates/either) crate. `Either` implements `Iterator` when both the left and right sides also implement `Iterator`, so it can be easily used to chain iterators together.

Given any three iterators `it`, `jt`, and `kt` that iterate over the same `Item`, with accompanying booleans `i`, `j`, and `k`, you can write a function that chains them together like this:

```rust
use either::Either;
use std::iter;

fn chain<'a, I, J, K, Item>(
    it: I,
    jt: J,
    kt: K,
    i: bool,
    j: bool,
    k: bool,
) -> iter::Chain<
    iter::Chain<Either<I, iter::Empty<Item>>, Either<J, iter::Empty<Item>>>,
    Either<K, iter::Empty<Item>>,
>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = Item>,
    J: Iterator<Item = Item>,
    K: Iterator<Item = Item>,
{
    let iter = if i {
        Either::Left(it)
    } else {
        Either::Right(iter::empty())
    };
    let iter = iter.chain(if j {
        Either::Left(jt)
    } else {
        Either::Right(iter::empty())
    });
    let iter = iter.chain(if k {
        Either::Left(kt)
    } else {
        Either::Right(iter::empty())
    });
    iter
}
```

Calling this function will result in an iterator conditional on the input. For example, calling

```rust
let it = [1, 2, 3].into_iter();
let jt = [4, 5, 6].into_iter();
let kt = [7, 8, 9].into_iter();

chain(it, jt, kt, true, false, true).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

gives

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```

as expected.

You can try it using this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=527ac63b03ae7abe5079399aa8133d89).